# Sheets function where if cell B2 and C2 repeat in another row toghether shows True, but if B2 repeats but C2 repeat in different rows, it shows False

Tags: google-sheets

Lets say that we have this:

**In B2 we have "123"
In C2 we have "1a2b"**

If B2 and C2 repeat in B17 and C17 toghether, show TRUE, But if B2 repeats in B4, but C2 repeats in C7, show FALSE. This condition applies to ALL rows, not just the ones in the examples.

I've tried this formula: `=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$1000,C2)>1, B2>1)` , but it didnt work as I needed.

[**Demo sheet of what i'm trying to achieve**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fzMXF9XFtNs2wJLOwi4VmKB3RmZSq3j_echoTHYcqKo/edit#gid=432831582)

Comment: It's not that clear what you want. Conditional formatting if both columns match with another row?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
=countifs($J$2:$J,$J2,$K$2:$K,$K2)>1
```

to highlight only rows matching in both columns?

[image]